# Is it possible to assign an array with anonymous functions to a class property in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, closures

***[Using PHP 5.5]***
So, I was trying to create a solution for loading Twig functions as they are appended to `$this->functions` (an array filled with the functions I want Twig to extend)

```
class Twig
{
    private $twig;
    private $templatesBaseDir = "../app/views";
    private $functions = [
        "lipsum" => function ($pcount, $psize) {
            return file_get_contents("http://loripsum.net/api/{$pcount}/{$psize}/headers");
        }
    ];

    /**
     * Sets Twig Environment configs
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($this->loadViews(), [
            "debug" => true,
            // "cache" => "/cache",
            "auto_reload" => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns Twig setup (environment configs + templates path)
     */
    public function loadTwig()
    {
        return $this->twig;
    }

    private function loadTwigFunctions()
    {
        foreach ($this->functions as $name => $closure) { 
            $$name = new \Twig_Function($name, $closure);
            $this->twig->addFunction($$name);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that PHP is returning an error for the line `"lipsum" => function ($pcount, $psize) {`:

> unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

I have done some tests with this approach into a global scope, using arrays and anonymous functions and it worked as expected, I guess it is some problem using it with class properties or something like that, not sure.

*(This is my first question here so let me know if more information are needed)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the initalization value of your property.

According to the [manual on properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> ... They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or
>   private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration
>   may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a
>   constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile
>   time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be
>   evaluated.

As an anonymous function cannot be evaluated at compile time, you cannot set it there.

It should work without any problems if you set the value of `$this->functions` in for example the constructor.

Comment: I tried with all my forces to upvote this answer. Thank you! :)))

Comment: @gpaulini I think you need at least 50 rep to be able to upvote. You can mark it as accepted though :-)